# Declaring a math operator for every capitalized word?

Tags: math-operators

I've declared a lot of math operators lately, e.g. `\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}, \DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}` and so forth. This is getting a bit annoying and seems automatable: what I'd really like is to have this behavior for every capitalized word, e.g. if I type `\Foo` in a document I'd like for this to be interpreted as a math operator without having to specify it in advance. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Every command must be defined before usage.

Comment: @egreg: but can't I do something like define a large class of operators at once in a loop? I think I remember seeing someone do something like this. (The hackiest thing would be to, say, declare all three- and four-letter capitalized math operators in advance.)

Comment: Does that mean that `\RequirePackage` should be reinterpreted as a math operator ;^)  ?

Answer (score 6):

Example for such a loop: `\DeclareMathOperators` takes a comma separated list of math operator names without backslash and turns them to math operator commands. Spaces and empty entries in the list are removed.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DeclareMathOperators}[1]{%
  \@for\@tmp:=#1\do{%
    % remove spaces
    \edef\@tmp{%
      \@firstofone{\expandafter\zap@space\@tmp} \@empty
    }%
    \ifx\@tmp\@empty
    \else
      % declare math operator
      \expandafter\DeclareMathOperator
      \csname\@tmp\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\@tmp}%
      % \wlog prints into the .log file
      % or \typeout can be used for console output                      
      \wlog{* Math operator "\@backslashchar \@tmp" defined.}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperators{
  End,
  Foo,
  Hom,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this? You cannot get closer to what you want than defining all used terms in a cycle.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\@for \op:={Dom,Hom}\do{
  \@ifundefined{\op}{
    \edef\DMOtemp{\noexpand\DeclareMathOperator{\csname\op\endcsname}{\op}}
    \DMOtemp
  }{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ \Dom A \neq \Hom B \]

\end{document}
```

We use LaTeX's `\@for` since `pgffor` makes grouping which makes definitions local and then it doesn't work. For each element of the list, we prepare the definition as `\DMOtemp->\DeclareMathOperator{\Dom}{Dom}`, and then we execute it. The `\@ifundefined` is quite necessary since if we wanted to re-define something, it would have bad consequences (the thing being re-defined would get executed at the line with `\edef` and the whole thing would probably fail). On the other hand, `\csname blabla\endcsname` for `\blabla` being undefined leaves just `\blabla` there, which is quite correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some example how to define a comma separated list of math operators:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}

\newcommand{\DeclareMathOp}[1]{
    \csgdef{#1}{\operatorname{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\DeclareMathOps}[1]{
    \forcsvlist{\DeclareMathOp}{#1}
}

\DeclareMathOp{HULL}
\DeclareMathOps{OPA,OPB,OPC}

\begin{document}
$\HULL\OPA\OPB$
\end{document}
```